# How to use the @RequestBody annotation in Spring MVC inheritance

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request

First, look at the following code

```
public interface DemoInterface {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test(@RequestParam String message);

}
```

Then I let a class implement this interface with annotations

```
@Controller
public class DemoClass implements DemoInterface{
    @Override
    public String test(String message) {
        /** TODO something useing the message **/
    }
}
```

This is no problem, I can access my test method via http://ip:port/test?message=something.

But when I need to pass a class instead of a string:

```
public interface DemoInterface {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes = "application/json")
    String test(@RequestBody User user);
}

public class User{
    private String name;
    /** some other fileds、 geters and seters **/
}

@Controller
publci class DemoClass implements DemoInterface{
    @Override
    public String test(User user) {
        /** TODO something useing the user's fileds **/
    }
}
```

At this time, although I can access http://ip:port/test, when I set the request body to json in the Google Chrome browser's Restlet Client, I can't get the user value in the test method, the name always empty. My json is like this:

```
{"name":"Vincent Kang"}
```

Is this because I can't get annotations for formal parameters in the methods I inherit? Because I found that even in the latter case, using http://ip:port/test?name=Kanghouchao, I can still get the name in the test method, 
RequestBody seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I should add @RequestBody in my subclass's field

```
@Controller
publci class DemoClass implements DemoInterface{
    @Override
    public String test(@RequestBody User user) {
        /** TODO something useing the user's fileds **/
    }
}
```

It's OK now

Comment: This is a known problem and has been fixed in Spring Framework 5.1 and soon will be fixed in Spring Boot 2.1. With the fix, you no longer need to repeat the annotation on the subclass.